# Error on reading a flat file

Tags: talend

I am trying to read a flat file via the tFileInputDelimited component and debug the results using a tLogCatcher.
I get the below errors while running the debug/run mode :

**Error in the component's properties:Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
filename_tFileInputDelimited_1 cannot be resolved to a variable
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
Syntax error on tokens, ( expected instead
Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens**

Any pointers to the right directions highly appreciated.

Comment: seems to be complaining about some property value. can you post the screenshot of your job showing the properties you have entered for the tfileinputdelimited component. you can also try to verify all properties you have entered for component are entered with valid values

Comment: check some where you are missing or having values with extra or less quotes